# Converting data with to_date function and combination of substrings

Tags: sql, oracle

some of my teammates messed up date format which is now in YYYY-DD-MM format 2013-24-09 in my table on Oracle database. I want to convert it into date format and try following code:

```
TO_DATE((SUBSTR(BEGINNING_DATE, 1, 4)||'-'||substr(BEGINNING_DATE, 9,2)||'-'||substr(BEGINNING_DATE,6, 2)), 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Still an error appears:

```
 ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  to_timestamp(): bad value 31 for day of the month
```

When I hower select seprate substrings into columns everything looks like below and I believe it is ok.

```
YYYY  MM DD
2013  12 31
```

I wonder where do I make mistake. Can you help me?

Comment: What is the data type of `BEGINNING_DATE`?

Comment: As of now it is stored as varchar.

Comment: Once you got that fixed, you should change that column to a `DATE` as soon as possible. You wouldn't have that problem if the column had been properly defined as `DATE` from the beginning

Comment: The case is that I want to convert with `CAST`  to a Date but whenever I try to do so it says: ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  Bad date external representation '2003-31-11'. That is why I try to fix it with substrings.

Comment: "30 days has ... November.". As I said in my answer, make sure all the dates are valid. November 31 is not a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is stored in the database as a string, and you just want a date out of it, `TO_DATE(BEGINNING_DATE, 'YYYY-DD-MM')` should suffice. You could then convert it back with TO_CHAR (with the correct format) if you're trying to fix the records in the database.

As for your particular error, if they are all stored as strings, you might want to check what value it is failing on, and make sure that one in particular is valid (e.g., it isn't '2013-02-31' or something).

Comment: With `TO_DATE(BEGINNING_DATE, 'YYYY-DD-MM') ` I ended up with: "ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  to_timestamp(): bad value 31 for day of the month"